# regex used to replace text failing

Tags: regex

I'm trying to replace `heelo|paul` in the following HTML, and replace it with `/heelo to paul/`

```
<p>Dear sir&nbsp;&nbsp; {{heelo|Paul}}&nbsp; ,</p>\n<p>I'm just testing please wait</p>\n<p>yours faithfully,</p>\n<p>&nbsp;
```

This is the regex I used:

```
str.replace(/.*?{{|}}/g, "/$1 to $2/")
```

But it generates the wrong result:

```
<p>Dear sir&nbsp;&nbsp; /$1 to $2/heelo|Paul/$1 to $2/&nbsp; ,</p>\n<p>I'm just testing please wait</p>\n<p>yours faithfully,</p>\n<p>&nbsp
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: No, I tried JavaScript and it does not give that output.

Comment: @melpomene Different javascript engines maybe?

Comment: @cshu No, OP didn't use a real example and made up the input/output for this question.

Comment: @clearlight Your edit changed the task description (it removed the `/.../` around the sample output).

Comment: All fixed. Thanks, and sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape `|` with `\`, and also adding groups to your desired matches. Try this regex:

```
(.*?{{)(.*?)\|(.*?)(?=}})
```

This is a working Javascript:

```js
var myString = "<p>Dear sir&nbsp;&nbsp; {{heelo|Paul}}&nbsp; ,</p>\n<p>I'm just testing please wait</p>\n<p>yours faithfully,</p>\n<p>&nbsp;";
document.write(myString.replace(/(.*?{{)(.*?)\|(.*?)(?=}})/g, "$1/$2 to $3/"));
```

Comment: I tried this but it's removing `Dear sir` part also

Comment: @kohli No, it doesn't remove it. Check out the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```js
var p = document.getElementById('greetings');
p.innerText = p.innerText.replace(/.*?\{\{([\w\s]+)\|([\w\s]+)\}\}/, "/$1 to $2/");
```

```html
<p id="greetings">Dear sir&nbsp;&nbsp; {{heelo|Paul}}&nbsp; ,</p>\n<p>I'm just testing please wait</p>\n<p>yours faithfully,</p>\n<p>&nbsp;
```